# Application with Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have created an application which includes `Crystal Reports` (basic edition 10.5). 
If I install it on computer which have Visual Studio installed, all work fine.
If I install it on the computer where there is no `Visual Studio`, there is an error.

**This is the stack track of it:**

```
    See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
 File name: 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..cctor()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
 To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument..ctor()
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass..ctor()
   at ProgramRoglic.CrystalReport1..ctor()
    at ProgramRoglic.Bill..ctor()
   at ProgramRoglic.Bill..ctor(CustomerData _customer, OrderData _order, List`1 _orderDetails)
   at ProgramRoglic.Orders.button8_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

--

I have a question: does the comupter which would run Crystal Reports needs to install Crystal Reports? Can I add them in the `Prerequisites`?

Thx

Comment: The answer is yes, you need to add it as prerequisite.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the client needs a Crystal Report viewer.

Here's a link you can use: http://www54.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports-viewer/index.html